# why there is a circuit breaker cut when I try to control NMOS

Tags: nmos

I'm trying to pilot NMOS but that doesn't work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyy7wF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No component is destroyed but the main electrical switch  is broken, I have to reactivate it.
I don't know if the diode rectifier can be placed like that.

- [NMOS Datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/90ef/0900766b814a679f.pdf).
- [Function generator](https://www.siglent.eu/product/1138488/siglent-sdg2122x-120mhz-function-arbitrary-waveform-generator).

The main electrical switch is the "safety device (RCD).
Thank you

Comment: There is no "main electrical switch" in your schematic diagram. We don't know what your 60 V and 1 V power supplies are made of. You need a lot more information in your question.

Comment: Are you using the word 'pilot' as a (mis)translation here? Would 'drive' possibly make more sense?

Comment: Yes means control the mosfetfor the "pilot"

Comment: The power supplies are classical DC voltage generator

Comment: There is no "classical DC voltage generator". There are isolated and non-isolated. There are transformer-rectifier type. There are switched mode power supplies. Most are isolated from mains earth. Some are not. The "main electrical switch" sounds like you mean a circuit breaker (but not a "security" device - maybe you mean safety device?). If you mean circuit breaker then is it a standard circuit breaker or an RCD/ELCB/GFCI type which trips on earth leakage current? Please supply the full details of your wiring and a datasheet link for the power supplies.

Comment: I modified the circuit, is it more clear ? Thanks

Comment: OK, so now it appears that your 60 V supply is full-wave rectified 230 V which will peak at 230\$\sqrt 2\$ V. Is the GND connected to mains earth / ground? What is the 1 V supply? Can you see that you have connected the bridge rectifier + directly to the L and the - directly to the N?

Comment: It looks like your rectifier output is connected directly to the mains. That can't be right.

Comment: Yes I wanted to simplify but finally it's better to show the entire circuit.                                     Can you see that you have connected the bridge rectifier + directly to the L and the - directly to the N? --> Yes but it works                                                                                  What is the 1 V supply?  This is a siglent SDG in DC mode

Comment: It looks like your rectifier output is connected directly to the mains. --> What is the mains ? Yes it is connected directly to the mosfet

Comment: You have shown a 230 V DC supply. Did you mean 230 V AC? "Mains" is the power supplied to your house. It is the "main" electrical supply (and not a battery, for example).

Comment: Yes it is 230 AC voltage. Ok I understand what's mains

Comment: **Stop playing with mains electricity before you kill yourself or burn down your house.** Working safely with mains requires a level of experience you clearly do not have. Stick with safe voltage and current levels (e.g. less than 30V and less than 5A) from an isolated power supply.

Comment: You have shorted out 2 of the diodes in the bridge rectifier!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you explain it  again with more information please?   My siglet generator shorted the resistor in the source because it is a non separated power supply.

Comment: Ok I make the schema I understand now, thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6aDs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The mains supply is short-circuited on negative half-cycles.*

You have shown a 230 V DC supply in your diagram. I presume it is 230 V **AC**. If so you have a short-circuit as shown in Figure 1. That should trip your circuit breaker. It may not be fast enough and BR1 may be destroyed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl3MGm.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Corrected schematic.*

It appears that you are not ready to work with mains voltage. I encourage you to find a low voltage circuit to work on.

---

From page 3 of the [Sigilent manual](https://www.batronix.com/files/Siglent/Funktionsgeneratoren/SDG2000X/SDG2000X_UserManual_EN.pdf):

> **Ground the Instrument.**
> The instrument is grounded through the protective ground conductor of the power line. To avoid electric shock, the ground conductor must be connected to the earth ground. Make sure the instrument is grounded correctly before connecting its input or output terminals.
> **Connect the signal wire correctly.**
> The potential of the signal wire ground is equal to the earth, therefore do not connect the signal wire to a high voltage. Do not touch the exposed contacts or components.

You cannot use the instrument on a live circuit the way you are using it. You risk electric shock and you might destroy the Siglent equipment.

Comment: Why it works when I retrieve the siglent generator ?

Comment: You said it doesn't work because it trips your main circuit breaker.

Comment: Are you really connecting the Sigilent generator to a circuit that is not isolated from the 230 V AC supply? You may destroy the generator because a high current may flow through the GND connection.

Comment: Whan I retrive the transistor part with generator, it works without any problem, I Have about 330 V DC,  when I put the transistor whithout supply, the gate isn't loaded (free gate), there is no problem, But when I plug the NMOS with siglent, there is a problem

Comment: No there is a security I think, that's why it the circuit break I thing.

Comment: In English that is a "safety device", not a security device. Kodi, you do not seem to understand what you are doing and the danger you and your equipment are in. You do not know enough to do this work. I advise you to stop and learn a lot more about mains electricity, grounding / earthing and how to work on isolated circuits safely.

Comment: Ok I will stop my expériences thank you for your advice, to control the transistor, I must use isolated generator ?

Comment: **NO**. You still do not understand. You must use **ISOLATED POWER SUPPLY** THAT IS NOT CONNECTED DIRECTLY TO THE MAINS. Stop now and get help from someone qualified who knows what they are doing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much